# Fonts displayed at larger size in documents compared to Windows

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I use Libreoffice both at home and at work. Unfortunately at work I use it under Windows, at home Ubuntu. Often I have to work on documents (especially ppt) started under Windows. Trouble is Ubuntu seems to display fonts as bigger (i.e. a sentence using font size 18 fits in a line under Windows, but under Ubuntu, using the same font and size it does not, which breaks formatting). Is there any way to make the font size display consistent between the two systems?

Comment: Are you using the same face in the two cases?  More than just size matters.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, for example Corbel. But this issue exists with all fonts I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

See the OpenOffice link with this problem, they suggest you download the "official" version instead of the Ubuntu version.  Probably applies to Libreoffice too.  I assume you really have the same fonts available and are not getting some substitution -- again see the link.
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=542